# How to change a function's action depend on who invoke it in python?

Tags: python, function, wrapper

Suppose we have four functions f, g1, g2, h, what I want is:
when f behaves different in g1(f) and g2(f), while h behaves the same when invoked by g1(h) and g2(h). Can any one give me some ideas?
For Example:

```
def g1(fun):
    ...
    print fun()
g1(f)   # prints: f in g1
g1(h)   # prints: h

def g2(fun):
    ...
    print fun()
g2(f)   # prints: f in g2
g2(h)   # prints: h
```

What I want to do is to write a test function, which some function were passed to two test functions and ont test function can judge sucess while the other can judge  fail. The function to be tested will dump different log while different test function was used.

Comment: Please tell us the actual problem you are trying to solve. There could be a better solution. Normally, a function should always give the same output for the same set of inputs. Practically it may not be possible in few of the cases, but that is what you should aim at.

Comment: @thefourtheye What I want to do is to write a test function, which some function were passed to two test functions and ont test function can judge sucess while the other can judge  fail.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you can add an argument to f and h:

```
def f(sender):
    return 'f' + str(sender)
def h(sender):
    return 'g' + str(sender)
def g1(fun):
    print(fun(0))
def g2(fun):
    print(fun(1))
g1(f)
g1(h)
g2(f)
g2(h)
```